# Associativity of Relativistic Oblique Velocity Addition

Tags: associativity, special-relativity

I've encountered some information in the *Wikipedia* page on **Lorentz transformation** (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) that I am having difficulty reconciling with other information that I found on the page (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation) on **Wigner rotation**. In the *Lorentz Transformation* page, it says that the *oblique* (non-collinear) Lorentz transformation is given by a matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}\gamma&-\gamma\beta n_x&-\gamma\beta n_y&-\gamma\beta n_z\\-\gamma\beta n_x&1+(\gamma-1)n_x^2&(\gamma-1)n_x n_y&(\gamma-1)n_z n_x\\-\gamma\beta n_y&(\gamma-1)n_x n_y&1+(\gamma-1)n_y^2&(\gamma-1)n_y n_z\\-\gamma\beta n_z&(\gamma-1)n_z n_x&(\gamma-1)n_y n_z2&1+(\gamma-1)n_z^2\end{pmatrix}$$ with the $n_q$ ($q\in\{x,y,z\}$) being the components of the unit vector along the direction-of-motion of the moving frame. And in the *Wigner Rotation* page, there is given the formula for oblique velocity addition that is derived from successive application of two such transformations $$\overrightarrow{\beta}_u\oplus\overrightarrow{\beta}_v=\frac{1}{1+\overrightarrow{\beta}_u.\overrightarrow{\beta}_v}\left[\left(1+\frac{\gamma_u\overrightarrow{\beta}_u.\overrightarrow{\beta}_v}{1+\gamma_u}\right)\overrightarrow{\beta}_u+\frac{\overline{\beta}_v}{\gamma_u}\right]$$$$\gamma_{\overrightarrow{\beta}_u\oplus\overrightarrow{\beta}_v}=\gamma_u\gamma_v(1+\overrightarrow{\beta}_u.\overrightarrow{\beta}_v) .$$ But then it goes on to say that in addition to being non-commutative (which I can well-accomodate), this recipe is also *non-associative*!:

"Although velocity addition is nonlinear, non-associative, and non-commutative, the result of the operation correctly obtains a velocity with a magnitude less than $c$.".

Now since the addition of velocities is derived from the application of successive transformations taking the mathematical form of *matrices*, which *are certainly associative*, how then  does the *non* -associativity of the addition of velocities come-about? For *three* consecutive Lorentz transformations would have result not contingent upon the *association* of the matrices - and the resultant velocity is *derived from* this product of three matrices ... so how can it come-about that the velocity addition be non-associative?

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have solved this.

Say you have four frames of reference labelled 0 to 3, the zeroth frame being the 'base' one, if you will; and let $Q_{ab}$ be the value of $Q$ - with Q being $\gamma$ or $\beta$ (or any other quantity, for that matter) - of frame $b$ relative to frame $a$, with $a\in\{0\dots3\}$ & $b\in\{0\dots3\}$. This way, $\beta_{01}$,  $\beta_{12}$ & $\beta_{23}$ - & therefore $\gamma_{01}$,  $\gamma_{12}$ & $\gamma_{23}$ are the *givens*. If you apply the formula first to find the velocity of frame 3 relative to frame 1, you would use the addition-of-velocity formula as given with $\gamma_u=\gamma_{12}$, $\beta_u=\beta_{12}$, & $\beta_v=\beta_{23}$, and the result would be $\beta_{13}$. Then to find the velocity of frame 3 relative to frame 0, you would simply iterate the formula with $\gamma_u=\gamma_{12}$, $\beta_u=\beta_{12}$, & $\beta_v=\beta_{23}$, and the result would be $\beta_{03}$ - the result sought. *However*, associating the calculation (*the calculation* that is! ... *not* the formula *itself*, as will shortly be apparent), you would first calculate $\beta_{02}$ by substituting $\gamma_u=\gamma_{01}$, $\beta_u=\beta_{01}$, & $\beta_v=\beta_{12}$. *But then* to calculate $\beta_{03}$ you would need to substitute $\gamma_u=\gamma_{02}$, $\beta_u=\beta_{02}$, & $\beta_v=\beta_{23}$. Note that in *this* association of the calculation $\gamma_{02}$ appears - which must be calculated *apart* using the ancilliary formula for composition of  the Lorentz factor.

So I think essentially what is being said in the *Wikipedia* article is that the formula is not associative *as it stands*, and is only applicable *as it stands* which is to say *without invoking the ancilliary formula for composition of Lorentz factors*, if the order of association is strictly from the uttermost-observed frame to the base-frame: that all other associations give the *wrong* result.

That's what I'm surmising, anyway. I haven't got *symbolic algebra computation* handy just at the moment; and I'm not crunching through all those substitutions using pencil & paper, & I haven't got the mental *calibre* necessary for doing it in my head. Oblique Lorentz transformations are notorious for the the sheer algeba-load of them being *formidable*! I'll report back when I've investigated the matter using a symbolic algebra package. But I think I probably do have the explanation here - I think my argument is logically *robust*.